# My code looks fine. Why am I getting a "error: expected primary-expression before ')' token"?

Tags: c++

Error on the denoted line below. What gives?

```
template <class T> T List<T>::count(T thisElement) { 
    node* curNodePtr = firstNodePtr;
    int cnt = 0;
    while (curNodePtr) { 
        if (curNodePtr->val == T) // error: expected primary-expression before ')'
            ++cnt;
        curNodePtr = curNodePtr->next;
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: You should also change the return type to `int`. I'm assuming counting the number of `T`s doesn't result in a `T`? :)

Answer (score 6):

```
template <class T> T List<T>::count(T thisElement) {
```

First of all, if you write a count method, I guess, that you rather want to return an `int` rather than `T`, so this line should look like this:

```
template <class T> int List<T>::count(T thisElement) {
```

Let's go on...

```
    if (curNodePtr->val == T)
```

I'm sure you wanted to write something like:

```
    if (curNodePtr->val == thisElement)
```

`T` is a type. If you later specialize your class with, say, `int`, your code line would become:

```
    if (curNodePtr->val == int)
```

This is why compiler complains.

Comment: @user3178285 Tired, I guess :)

Comment: They probably want to return `std::size_t`.

Comment: @juanchopanza In such case they should also change `int cnt;` to `std::size_t cnt;`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I getting a “error: expected primary-expression before ')' token”?

Because `T` is a type. You need to compare to an instance. For example, `T()`.

```
if (curNodePtr->val == T()) ....
                        ^^
```

Besides that, you have to make sure your function actually does something sensible. That is another matter.

Comment: That won't help much. This function is meant to count, how many times `thisElement` appears on the list, so this line should look like: `if (curNodePtr->val == thisElement) ...`.

Comment: @Spook I am not going to start second guessing OP's logic. I fixed the error they are asking about. If the function doesn't do whatever they expect it to do, they can ask another question.

Comment: @Spook just about average :)